# Error getting the correct route in console Angular2

Tags: angular, url, angular2-routing, console.log

I am trying to print my current route to console log i tried to print the route using url property of Router. It only shows `/` as the route even though the original route is `/profile`. I tried print the whole Router object to the console, there I can see url field shown like this:`url:(...)`. When I click the `(...)` the oroginal path is shown like `url:"\profile"`. `(...)` shows "invoke property getter" on hover.The following is the code to print the url to console.I am on angular 2.4.0.

```
  import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
  import {SignupService} from '../../services/signup.service';
  import {Auth} from '../../services/auth.service';
  import {AppRoutingModule} from '../../routes/app.routing';
  import {Router} from '@angular/router';
  declare var $: any;


  @Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/navbar.css'],
  })
  export class NavbarComponent  {
    constructor(private auth: Auth, private router:Router ){
      console.log(this.router.url);   
    };
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();  
      }

  }
```

Comment: Please do help. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this solutions.

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

constructor(locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) {
  console.log(locationStrategy);
}
```

check these examples [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xvwySO0pwRXUn9CUXcJu?p=preview) (check browser console to see results)

Comment: As I know It shows the path relative to your component